# Regex Search to Check Multiple Conditions in a String

Tags: python, regex

I am new to using regex and use Python, and to gain some practice I thought I should write a program that would simulate checking conditions for a username and password.  The password requirements I want are:

```
# 1. have one or more special characters
# 2. have one or more lowercase letters
# 3. have one or more uppercase letters
# 4. have one or more numbers
```

But the variable I came up with...

```
req_characters = r"([@#$%&*-_/\.!])+([a-z])+([A-Z])+([0-9])+"
```

and the regex search function...

```
    elif not re.search(req_characters, string):
    print("Your password must contain at least one uppercase and one 
           lowercase letter, one number, and one special character.")
```

results in strings that should match, triggering that if statement.  Specifically, if I enter the string

```
#This_is_stuff0123
```

I get the print statement, so the regex thinks the conditions haven't been met.  However, if I enter the string

```
##azAZ01
```

it matches, which tells me the regex will only take those character classes/groups in order.  I tried various groupings with parentheses to no avail, and then tried using "or" in the following way, with the same result:

```
req_characters = r"([@#$%&*-_/\.!]|[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-9]){6, 30}"
```

so I'm wondering what a simple solution might be to edit the current regex to achieve this result.

Comment: You need positive lookaheads to check various criteria as the characters can be in any order.

Comment: As with every regex question: does it really have to be a regex? Does it really have to be a single regex?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure, if [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/69Yn18/1) might match all your inputs, however it might help you to design an expression to do so:

```
 ^(?=.+[@#$%&*-_\/\.!])(?=.+[a-z])(?=.+[A-Z])(?=.+[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#$%&*-_\/\.!]{6,30}$
```

[image]

#### Code:

```
import re

string = 'A08a^&0azA'
# string = 'A08a^&0azAadA08a^&0azAadA08a^&0azAad'
matches = re.search(r'^((?=.+[@#$%&*-_\/\.!])(?=.+[a-z])(?=.+[A-Z])(?=.+[0-9])[A-Za-z0-9@#$%&*-_\/\.!]{6,30})$', string)
if matches:
    print(matches.group(1)+ " is a match")
else: 
    print('Sorry! No matches! Something is not right! Call 911')
```

#### Output

```
A08a^&0azA is a match
```

#### Graph

[image]